# Computing Conjugacy Classes of Subgroups in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, computer-algebra-systems, gap

GAP has the command ConjugacyClassesSubgroups which gives a list of the conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$.  Is there a way I can specify further what types of subgroups GAP reports?  For instance, can I ask GAP to only list conjugacy classes of subgroups of a certain order or isomorphism type?

I'm interested in computing $p$-groups, and I'm hoping to cut down on computation time by instructing GAP to ignore all other subgroups.

Magma has parameters like OrderEqual and OrderDividing when computing subgroups.  I'm looking for a similar function with GAP.

Comment: You could try doing something like finding a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$, then finding maximal subgroups of $P$, then testing these for conjugacy in $G$ and keeping only one representative in each $G$-class, then finding all of their maximal subgroups, etc.

Comment: Another sneaky method uses the table of marks library in GAP. Some kind soul computed the subgroup lattice and wrote down the answer. However, I personally have not learned to use it effectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you may find helpful some functions like `NormalSubgroups`, `IsomorphicSubgroups` etc. which are listed in ["How do I get the subgroups of my group?"](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7) entry from the GAP F.A.Q. There are also further functions not listed there, such as `RepresentativesPerfectSubgroups`, `RepresentativesSimpleSubgroups`, `ConjugacyClassesMaximalSubgroups` - see Chapter "Groups" from the GAP manual for more functions with the similar semantics.

Regarding *p*-subgroups, the manual entry for `IsomorphicSubgroups` suggests the same approach as in the Derek Holt's comment above: "To find *p*-subgroups it is often faster to compute the subgroup lattice of the Sylow subgroup".

Furthermore, `LatticeByCyclicExtension` and `SubgroupsSolvableGroup` accept optional arguments which allow to put restrictions on computed subgroups. In the latter case functions `SizeConsiderFunction` and `ExactSizeConsiderFunction` may be used. All four functions mentioned in this paragraph are documented in the Chapter "Groups", type e.g. `?SubgroupsSolvableGroup` to see their descriptions in GAP.

As for tables of marks mentioned by Jack Schmidt, see Chapter "Tables of Marks" and in particular Section "Accessing Subgroups via Tables of Marks" - but that will work only for groups whose tables are contained in the tables of marks library.

Comment: Dear Alexander - maybe this is a practical question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760827/conjugacy-classes-and-centralizers-of-a-smallgroup?lq=1