# How to find presentation of a group using GAP?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, computational-algebra

I have a group from [Small Group Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html) and I want to find its presentation using GAP.

I have tried to use *PresentationFpGroup(G)* but failed.

Please suggest me a method.

Comment: Try IsomorphismFpGroup

Comment: I've recently shown how to use `IsomorphismFpGroup ` at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/760827/). Please see also `?SimplifiedFpGroup` in GAP.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Could we do this question, as you kindly did it below, for finite semigroups? However, this question was for 3 years ago. Regards.

Comment: @ResidentDementor Why don't you post a new question, formulated for finite semigroups, on this site?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Overview.

If `G` is the group you want a presentation for, first use

```
H:=Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(G));
```

to transform `G` into a FPGroup type.  GAP will output the generators.  Then follow up with

```
RelatorsOfFpGroup(H);
```

to see the relations.

#### Remark.

Sometimes it may be helpful to call `SimplifiedFpGroup` like here:

```
H:=SimplifiedFpGroup(Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(G)));
```

in order to obtain a presentation of a simpler form.

---

### Example.

The following example demonstrates this for the dihedral group of order 256. First we will figure out its ID and extract it from the Small Groups Library:

```
gap> D:=DihedralGroup(256);
<pc group of size 256 with 8 generators>
gap> IdGroup(D);
[ 256, 539 ]
gap> G:=SmallGroup(256,539);
<pc group of size 256 with 8 generators>
```

It is given by a presentation of special kind, called *polycyclic presentation*. This is very efficient to process this group on a computer, but not very efficient for processing by humans:

```
gap> H:=Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(G));
<fp group of size 256 on the generators [ F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8 ]>
gap> RelatorsOfFpGroup(H);
[ F1^2, F2^-1*F1^-1*F2*F1*F3^-1, F3^-1*F1^-1*F3*F1*F4^-1, F4^-1*F1^-1*F4*F1*F5^-1, 
  F5^-1*F1^-1*F5*F1*F6^-1, F6^-1*F1^-1*F6*F1*F7^-1, F7^-1*F1^-1*F7*F1*F8^-1, 
  F8^-1*F1^-1*F8*F1, F2^2, F3^-1*F2^-1*F3*F2*F4^-1, F4^-1*F2^-1*F4*F2*F5^-1, 
  F5^-1*F2^-1*F5*F2*F6^-1, F6^-1*F2^-1*F6*F2*F7^-1, F7^-1*F2^-1*F7*F2*F8^-1, 
  F8^-1*F2^-1*F8*F2, F3^2*F5^-1*F4^-1, F4^-1*F3^-1*F4*F3, F5^-1*F3^-1*F5*F3, 
  F6^-1*F3^-1*F6*F3, F7^-1*F3^-1*F7*F3, F8^-1*F3^-1*F8*F3, F4^2*F6^-1*F5^-1, 
  F5^-1*F4^-1*F5*F4, F6^-1*F4^-1*F6*F4, F7^-1*F4^-1*F7*F4, F8^-1*F4^-1*F8*F4, 
  F5^2*F7^-1*F6^-1, F6^-1*F5^-1*F6*F5, F7^-1*F5^-1*F7*F5, F8^-1*F5^-1*F8*F5, 
  F6^2*F8^-1*F7^-1, F7^-1*F6^-1*F7*F6, F8^-1*F6^-1*F8*F6, F7^2*F8^-1, F8^-1*F7^-1*F8*F7, 
  F8^2 ]
```

Luckily, in this case `SimplifiedFpGroup` produces much shorter presentation:

```
gap> K:=SimplifiedFpGroup(H);
<fp group on the generators [ F1, F2 ]>
gap> RelatorsOfFpGroup(K);
[ F1^2, F2^2, (F1*F2)^128 ]
```

Just to show that all these three groups are isomorphic,

```
gap> List([G,H,K],StructureDescription);
[ "D256", "D256", "D256" ]
```

Note that if the connection to the original group is important, then the operation `IsomorphismSimplifiedFpGroup` should be used instead of `SimplifiedFpGroup`. Furthermore, if for some concrete group the resulting presentation is unsatisfying, then one could try more sophisticated interactive use of Tietze transformation commands available in GAP (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap48.html)).

Comment: I, personally, preferred to know the answer of this question when we have semigroups instead of groups, however; there are some similar codes. +1

Comment: @Resident feel free to edit in a section to include that code in this answer. It is CW, so there is no owner.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Dear Alexander, what should we do for questions about GAP so far? Should them ask at MSE or at Stackoverflow. Sometimes, I am wonder where to ask them. I don't want to make any defects in whole system. If you think, they should be there, please send my questions about GAP to there site. Regards.

Comment: @Resident Dementor I would ask GAP questions on MSE. They are on-topic both here and on StackOverflow, but I wager it is more likely to get an answer at MSE. In other news, there is a GAP email list that serves as a forum and is very active, so you may want to look into that if you're using GAP often.