# How to test number of containments in subgroups with GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Here it is: for a given soluble group $G$, I want to test whether 
the number of Carter subgroups containing a given nilpotent subgroup $N$ of $G$
is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo a certain number $m(G)$, depending on $G$
and defined by $m(G) = \gcd\left\{p-1 : p \mid |G|,\, p \,\text{prime}\right\}$. Since I want $N$ to be arbitrary, I want this test for all nilpotent subgroups of $G$.

Of course, the question is pointless if $G$ is nilpotent, so I would also like to ask how to obtain a filtered list of all soluble but non-nilpotent groups up to a given order (say 100).

---

For reference, based on Max's suggestions:

```
LoadPackage("format”);;
count := function(G, N) 
return 
Number(ConjugacyClassSubgroups(G, CarterSubgroup(G)), x -> IsSubgroup(x, N)); 
end;;

grps := AllSmallGroups([1..100], IsNilpotentGroup, false, IsSolvableGroup, true);;

for i in [1..Length(grps)] do
  G := grps[i];;
  nilsubs := Filtered(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),Representative),IsNilpotentGroup);;
  for N in nilsubs do
    if count(G,N) > 0 then
      m := G -> Gcd(List(Set(Factors(Size(G))), p -> p-1));;
      if count(G,N) mod m(G) > 1 then
        Print(false);
      fi;
    fi;
  od;
od;
```

Comment: This should not be complicated (at least for groups of reasonable orders). See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/460727/ for conjugacy classes of subgroups, and [GAP Software Carpentry Lesson](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups.html) for examples of using [GAP Small Groups Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html)

Comment: I know what I'm asking is easy, but I don't have the patience to try and remember what little I knew of GAP from before, so I am essentially looking for someone to do this work for me. I'll start a bounty as soon as possible.

Comment: It would be good if you clarified what you exactly *want*. So what exactly is missing in the code I provided, resp. the code you derived from it?

Comment: You first say: "For a given nilpotent subgroup" -- my code handles that code. You then say: "I want this test for all nilpotent subgroups of G", which technically I also did (note that your statement was/is ambiguous). Based on your example code, it seems you just want to print a long list of false and true (instead of, say, counting how many of which kind you see). That sounds rather pointless to me, so I assume you want to know something else. But what is a mystery....

Comment: What I really want is to see if there is a soluble, non-nilpotent group $G$ with a Carter subgroup $C$ and a nilpotent subgroup $N$ such that the number of containments of $N$ in conjugates of $C$ is at least one but not congruent to $1 \pmod{m_G}$. The first requirement is obvious, since there are, in general, nilpotent subgroups not contained in any Carter subgroup. However, if $N$ is contained in at least one Carter subgroup, then I conjecture that the aforementioned congruence holds, and I'd like to have some computational evidence verifying this.

Comment: Also, note that I'm only asking GAP to print a "false" if it finds a counterexample; otherwise, it shouldn't print anything.

Comment: Aha, so if that's what you really want, I recommend clarifying your question accordingly :-). In that case, you really need to look at each conjugacy class of nilpotent subgroups once (i.e. use `Representative`, not `Elements`), as the count will be the same for conjugate subgroups.

Comment: Right, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GAP package [FORMAT](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/format.html) allows computing things like Carter subgroups.

To compute all solvable but not nilpotent groups of order up to 100, you can use this:

```
gap> grps := AllSmallGroups([1..100], IsNilpotentGroup, false, IsSolvableGroup, true);;
gap> Length(grps);
463
```

So let's look at some examples

```
gap> LoadPackage("format");
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Loading  FORMAT 1.3 (Formations of Finite Soluble Groups)
by Bettina Eick (http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~beick) and
   Charles R.B. Wright (http://www.uoregon.edu/~wright).
Homepage: http://www.uoregon.edu/~wright/RESEARCH/format/
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
true
gap> grps := AllSmallGroups([1..100], IsNilpotentGroup, false, IsSolvableGroup, true);;
gap> G := grps[100]; # some arbitrary group
<pc group of size 50 with 3 generators>
gap> N := NormalSubgroups(G)[3]; # some normal subgroup
Group([ f3 ])
gap> N := Group(G.1*G.3);; # some nilpotent subgroup
gap> IsNilpotentGroup(N);
true
```

Since all Carter subgroups of a finite solvable group are conjugate, we can count how many of them contain $N$ quite easily:

```
gap> count := function(G, N) return Number(ConjugacyClassSubgroups(G, CarterSubgroup(G)), x -> IsSubgroup(x, N)); end;;
gap> count(G,N);
1
```

Finally, you can compute the value mod $m(G)$ as follows:

```
gap> m := G -> Gcd(List(Set(Factors(Size(G))), p -> p-1));;
gap> count(G,N) mod m(G);
0
```

---

UPDATE: Your comments indicate that what you really want to do is to test a conjecture which states that a certain number is always 0 or 1. The code you wrote based on my post does that; I edited it slightly to make it a bit faster.

UPDATE 2: Per your request, I changed the code to skip the case where the Carter subgroup is a Hall subgroup.

```
LoadPackage("format");;
count := function(G, N) 
  return Number(ConjugacyClassSubgroups(G, CarterSubgroup(G)),
        x -> IsSubgroup(x, N)); 
end;;
m := G -> Gcd(List(Set(Factors(Size(G))), p -> p-1));;

grps := AllSmallGroups([1..100], IsNilpotentGroup, false, IsSolvableGroup, true);;

for i in [1..Length(grps)] do
  if i mod 50 = 0 then Print(i, " of ", Length(grps), "\n"); fi;
  G := grps[i];;

  # skip if Carter subgroup is a Hall subgroup
  H := CarterSubgroup(G);
  if Gcd(Size(H), Index(G, H)) = 1 then continue; fi;

  nilsubs := Filtered(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),Representative),IsNilpotentGroup);;
  mG := m(G);
  for N in nilsubs do
    if count(G,N) mod mG > 1 then
      Print("Group ", IdGroup(G), " provides an example\n");
    fi;
  od;
od;
```

Comment: Thanks, that comes quite close to what I want. If I may trouble you a little further, how can I iterate (for a given group in the list grps) over all nilpotent subgroups?

Comment: Use something like this to get one representative of each conjugacy class of nilpotent groups: Filtered(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),Representative),IsNilpotentGroup)

Comment: I am not clear whether Representative (rather than Elements) suffice. Let me put down what I compile and maybe you can comment on the correctness of that. I will then award the bounty.

Comment: For elementary reasons, the count is the same for every $N$ in the same conjugacy class. So, if you want to try larger examples, you should definitely work with representatives. This, together with the size of the conjugacy class, gives the same information

Comment: A (hopefully) final question: how can I exclude from the list grps those soluble groups whose Carter subgroups are Hall? Because in that case I already have a proof that the desired congruence holds.

Comment: I updated the code to skip Hall subgroups (which are trivial to detect: it's a subgroup whose size is coprime to its index).

Comment: That looks perfect, thanks a lot :) I tried something myself: `if GcdInt(Order(CarterSubgroup(G)),Index(G,CarterSubgroup(G)))>1 then`, but I see now that we did the same thing, pretty much. I guess I was asking about the possibility to exclude these by adding an extra filter in grps. Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: Apologies for reopening this. I'd like to ask: might you be able to offer advice how to extend the search to other groups in the SmallGroups library, excluding those of order at most 2000? That is to say, suppose the code finishes searching in AllSmallGroups([1..2000],..) . Where else might I look next? Chap. 50 of the GAP manual doesn't shed much light, nor does a read file I've found in the homepage of the Small Groups library.

Comment: Just replace the list grps by your list of groups, and run the program...

Comment: I didn't express myself correctly, sorry. For example, how can I search among all groups of cube-free order and less than 50000?

Comment: These are all in the small groups library.

Comment: Yes, I see that! How can I access them though?

Comment: Replace the range [1..100] by whatever orders you want to investigate. If you still don't see how, please open a new question.

Comment: So you suggest to try AllSmallGroups([3000..3100]..), is that it? Ok, cool.

Comment: Do you see some way of using double cosets to speed up the computation of the function `count`? I can open a new question if that is preferable.

Comment: You should certainly open a new question, if only to increase the chance that somebody might give a useful answer (a new question will draw more attention then a comment on an answer to an old question...)

Comment: Also, if you have speed concerns, I'd make sure to state an example where the current (admitedly completly naive) implementation is (relativel) slow.